# How can I persist id_token to use during sign out?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, identityserver4, identity, okta

I'm using Okta, .NET 6 and Identity Server 4 (in the middle of convincing the upper management to upgrade from 4.0 to 6.0).

I need the `id_token` in order to log out from Okta, however it's always `null`.

The following methods are from my custom `OpenIdConnectEvents` class:

Here I persist the token so it's available in the `OnTicketReceivedImpl` event:

```
private Task OnTokenResponseReceivedImpl(TokenResponseReceivedContext context)
{
    context.Properties?.StoreTokens(new[]
    {
        new AuthenticationToken
        {
            Name = "id_token",
            Value = context.TokenEndpointResponse.IdToken
        }
    });

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Here I add the claim:

```
    private Task OnTicketReceivedImpl(TicketReceivedContext context)
    {
        var idToken = context.Properties?.Items[".Token.id_token"];
        if (idToken != null)
        {
            ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal?.Identity)?.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", idToken));
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

You can see the `id_token` was added to the `Claims`:

[image]

However, when I try to access the `id_token` during log out, it's `null`:

```
private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOutImpl(RedirectContext context)
{
    var oidcMessage = context.ProtocolMessage;
    // Which one of these methods should I use?
    var idTokenClaim1 = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("id_token"); // null
    var idTokenClaim = context.Properties.GetTokenValue("id_token"); // null
    if (idTokenClaim != null)
    {
        oidcMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenClaim;
        oidcMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = HomeUrl.AbsoluteUri;
    }
    ...
}
```

Here you can see there is no `id_token` claim, but a claim called `idp` has been added and has a value of `"local"`.

[image]

Here's my `Startup.ConfigureServices()`:

```
    services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) // "Cookies"
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "OpenIdConnect", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme; // "idsrv.external"
                options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme; // "idsrv"
                options.Authority = "https://saas.oktapreview.com";
                options.ClientId = "clientIdHere";
                options.ClientSecret = "secretHere";
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("phone");
                options.Events = new IrmOpenIdConnectEvents();
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });
```

How can I access the `id_token` during sign out?

Comment: The `options.SaveTokens = true;` should save the `id_token` for you. You should be able to retrieve it with `var idToken = await context.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");` after that. No need to manually copy it to user claims.

Comment: `GetTokenAsync()` returns `null` even with `options.SaveTokens = true;`.

Comment: Try to pass the schema name to `GetTokenAsync` method.